# broadcast not supported by sql broker transport

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, celery

I am getting this error with my celery configuration.Emails are not working for notifications. when i check status with

```
python manage.py celery -A app status
```

it gives me :

```
broadcast not supported by sql broker transport
```

My celeryconfig.py has following settings:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
```

My set up is Django 1.6 + celery3.1.12 + postgresql + gunicorn

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The error message actually says it all:

"Error: Broadcast not supported by SQL broker transport".

From [Celery 3.1 documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/django.html#limitations),

> **Limitations**
>
> The Django database transport does not currently support:
>
> - Remote control commands (celery events command, broadcast)
> - Events, including the Django Admin monitor.
> - Using more than a few workers (can lead to messages being executed multiple times).

`status` is one of the [monitoring commands](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/monitoring.html#commands).